# How to not loose <pre> and <iframe> when converting HTML to Markdown?

Tags: html, node.js, markdown

I've got a couple of html files which I'd like to automatically convert to markdown using Node.js. My problem is – while converting there seem to be couple of tags lost, especially `<iframe>` and `<pre>`.

Here is an example of the issue:

**example.html**

```html
<h1>My title</h1>
I present you my code:
<pre>console.log('hello world!');</pre>
```

**converted.md**

```
# My title
I present you my code:
```

As you can see, the `<pre>` element is gone :-( I understand that there is no markdown equivalent to these tags but since every html code is also valid in md files, shouldn't these just remain as pure html within the md file?

**what-I-expected.md**

```
# My title
I present you my code:
<pre>console.log('hello world!');</pre>
```

The converter I created is written in Node and looks like this:

```
var TurndownService = require('turndown')

function post2Markdown(post) {
  var turndownService = new TurndownService()
  var contentAsMarkdown = turndownService.turndown(post.content.rendered)

  return contentAsMarkdown
}
```

Is this just a problem with the Turndown library I'm using here or is it a general thing that html->md converters do? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "*since every html code is also valid in md files, shouldn't these just remain as pure html within the md file?*" I'm not that familiar with Markdown processors and how they are used but I'd assume that what they do is completely valid default thing. One of the reason you want to use Markdown is to reduce your threat surface - if you don't allow users to enter just any HTML, you have less to worry about. So, removing any tags Markdown doesn't have an equivalent for seems perfectly reasonable - after all, it could have been `<script src="badScript.js"></script>` or just mess up formatting.

Comment: @VLAZ Good point! Yes, security is really important. I don't see any issues allowing `<pre>` for example.

Comment: Yes, this is a risk you have to opt into. Although note that even if a particular tag might still present a problem, even if it's not a security issue. It might introduce formatting that's undesirable, for example. Broken tags might even break the entire page (e.g., an unclosed bold tag). Markdown ensures that anything you put in it will be formatted *coherently* - if you screw up the Markdown syntax, you don't get invalid HTML and you also always get HTML output that is predictable. So, it's still reasonable to prune unsupported content by default and allow you to opt into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read how turndown works?

According to [Turndown documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turndown#keepfilter), the option `keep` is what you need.

The code below should do the job:

```
var TurndownService = require('turndown')

function post2Markdown(post) {
  var turndownService = new TurndownService()
  turndownService.keep(['pre', 'iframe'])
  var contentAsMarkdown = turndownService.turndown(post.content.rendered)

  return contentAsMarkdown
}
```